# Embedding an object inside another object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to duplicate a complex object. The orginal object is like

```
         Note note = db.Notes.FirstorDefault(n............);
```

When I mouse over the Note object is see this stuctor

Note | Data.Model.Note

If drill down I see

Base Data.Model.AnalyNote

If drill down again I see

Base Data.Model CPObject

if look at the varible "note" I see this in the first layer

> ```
>          +base Data.Model.Note
>          +AnalyNotes
>           FisYear
>           Quarter
>           QReport
> ```

If I look at the second layer

> ```
>          +base Data.Model.AnalyNote
>          +Attachments
>          +Classify
>           Headline
>           IsDraft
> ```

If I go to third layer

> ```
>          +Data.Model.CPObject
>           EntryId
>          +EntryDate
>           Id
> ```

Each of these ( Note, AnalyNote, CPObject ) are seperate Models. I can create the seperate Models but do not understand how to embed them to duplicate the orginal Note model. I created the three
using

```
         var NNotes = new Notes()
         {
            data.....
         }

         var AAnote = new AnalyNote()
         {
            data......
         }

         var CPONote = new CPObject()
         {
            data.....
         }
```

This is as far as I have gotten.

Answer (score 3):

There's two things going on here:

1. from your drill-down, it seems that Data.Model.Note inherits from Data.Model.AnalyNote, which inherits from Data.Model.CPObject (I'm assuming you left a period out of the namespace for CPObject). So you don't need to create all three, just the Data.Model.Note. MVC should take care of the modeling work for you.
2. If you are getting your Note from something that implements [iCloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx), your work may be as simple as

   `Note note = db.Notes.FirstorDefault(n............);
   Note duplicate = note.Clone();`

---

From your comment below, it sounds like you're trying to sub-class your Note model. It sounds like you don't have any data behind your model yet, so a code-first approach might be good. You might make a new model like so

```
class Data.Model.NewerNote : Data.Model.Note
{
// the new fields ("variables") would go here.
     public int NoteFoo {get; set;}
     public DateTime NoteFrob {get; set;}
// and so on.
}
```

You may find a reference book like [Programming Entity Framework: Code First](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022220.do) or [Programming ASP.NET MVC 4](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024040.do) of use here.

Comment: Guess what I am doing is not totally a duplicate. The new Note Module will have some extra varibles in the models but I need the structor to be like the orginal model. They want to expand some of the model. I might not be explaining myself correctly. Basicly I need to create a new model with extra varibles that inherits like the orginal model?

Answer (score 0):

Although I think Reacher Gilts answer correctly analyzes your situation, if you want to 'embed one object in another' this is referred to as composition and it's as simple as declaring a new class who's members are instances of those other three classes.

```
public class OuterNote
{
    NNote nNote;
    AAnote aaNote;
    CPONote cpoNote;

   public OuterNote()
   {
       nNote = new NNote();
       aaNote = new AANote();
       cpoNote = new CPONote();
   }

   // add other constructors or initializers to this class and the others needed
}
```